# Javascript Codility Maximum Slice problem

Tags: javascript, algorithm, slice

Im attempting the following algorithm problem in Javascript from Codility:

An array A consisting of N integers is given.
It contains daily prices of a stock share for a period of N consecutive days.
If a single share was bought on day **P** and sold on day **Q**,
 where `0 ≤ P ≤ Q < N`,
then the profit of such transaction is equal to `A[Q] − A[P]`,
provided that `A[Q] ≥ A[P]`.

Otherwise, the transaction brings loss of `A[P] − A[Q]`.

For example, consider the following array A consisting of six elements such that:

```
  A[0] = 23171
  A[1] = 21011
  A[2] = 21123
  A[3] = 21366
  A[4] = 21013
  A[5] = 21367
```

If a share was bought on day 0 and sold on day 2, a loss of `2048` would occur because `A[2] − A[0] = 21123 − 23171 = −2048`.
If a share was bought on day 4 and sold on day 5, a profit of `354` would occur because `A[5] − A[4] = 21367 − 21013 = 354`.
Maximum possible profit was `356`.
It would occur if a share was bought on day 1 and sold on day 5.

Write a function,

function solution(A);

that, given an array A consisting of N integers containing daily prices of a stock share for a period of N consecutive days, returns the maximum possible profit from one transaction during this period.
The function should return 0 if it was impossible to gain any profit.

For example, given array A consisting of six elements such that:

```
  A[0] = 23171
  A[1] = 21011
  A[2] = 21123
  A[3] = 21366
  A[4] = 21013
  A[5] = 21367
```

the function should return `356`, as explained above.

Write an efficient algorithm for the following assumptions:

`N` is an integer within the range `[0..400,000]`;
each element of `array A` is an integer within the range `[0..200,000]`.

This is my current solution, it fails on performance on 'chaotic sequence of 200K values from [100K..120K], then 200K values from [0..100K]' where it succeeds 0.07 seconds too late.

```
function solution(A) {
    length = A.length
    if (A > 400000) return 0
    let lastStart = A[0]
    let lastMax = A[0]
    let diff = 0
    for (i=0; i < length; i++){
        if (A[i] < lastMax) lastMax = A[i]
        if (A[i] < lastStart) lastStart = A[i]
        if (A[i] > lastMax) {
            lastMax = A[i]
            if (lastMax - lastStart > diff) diff = lastMax - lastStart
        }
    }
    return diff > 0 ? diff : 0
}
```

This appears to be O(N) and so should pass but seems to be failing.
Can anyone see what is causing this.
I know there are other ways to solve this problem but I really want to know why this method is failing the time limit.

Thanks!

Comment: You could save `lastMax - lastStart` in a variable instead of calculating it twice. You should also use local variables, never implicitly create global variables (it's both sloppy and can result in longer execution time IIRC)

Comment: I wonder what `A > 400000` actually does. I assume you meant `length > 400000`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the fastest algorithm ( O(N) ) based on max slice probe algorithm in Python.

```
def solution(A):
 if(len(A)==0):
     return 0
 else:
     min_start= A[0]
     max_profit = 0
     for a in A:
         min_start = min(a, min_start)
         max_profit = max(max_profit, a - min_start)
     return max_profit
```

Answer (score 0):

It is as simple as that (passes all tests):

```
function solution(A) {
    let min = A[0]
    let dif = 0
    for (let i = 1; i < A.length; i++) {
        if (A[i] < min)
            min = A[i]
        else if (A[i] - min > dif)
            dif = A[i] - min
    }
    return dif
}
```

- The following line is doing nothing: `if (A > 400000) return 0`.
- Here you should probably change the `<` to `>` or omit the line completely: `if (A[i] < lastMax) lastMax = A[i]`.
- Your logic seems to be wrong, you only change `diff` if you see a new max. Although it doesn't matter, because you reset `lastMax` before.

So your code seems to work correctly, just some minor improvements. My guess is that if many people are submitting solutions simultaneously then it is taking longer and you fail the performance test.

Comment: it passes as correct and all other performance tests it only fails that specific performance test

Comment: @HappyMachine maybe it depends on how many people are submitting solutions simultaneously. Actually I submitted your code (just removed the if (A>400000) and it passed all tests.

Comment: thats interesting that would suggest that the check is enough to throw performance, im having the same problem with another algorithm i cant improove on. Thanks, I will check this!

Answer (score 0):

This simple solution in **C**.
https://app.codility.com/demo/results/trainingVTW26A-737/

Detected time complexity:
*O(N)*

```
int solution(int A[], int N) {
    // write your code in C99 (gcc 6.2.0)

    int i, sum, max, globalMax;

    sum = 0;
    max = globalMax = A[0];

    for (i = 1 ; i < N; ++i) 
    {
        sum = A[i] + max;
        max = (sum > A[i]) ? sum : A[i];

        if (max > globalMax) 
        {
            globalMax = max;
        }
    } 

    return globalMax;
}
```